# Unable to insert/print out the whole Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build my own library of Binary Search Tree (BST) in C language. However, I find it hard to insert or print out the whole binary tree. For detail, this is the struct of each Binary Node, in which `Object` has been predefined already.

```
struct BinaryNode
{
    Object item;
    BinaryNode *left;
    BinaryNode *right;
};
```

This is the source code of `insert` operation which followed precisely the properties of Binary Search Tree as following. The `root` pointer is the global variable that holds the head of Binary Search Tree and `Newnode()` is the function that creates a new node to insert into the Binary Search Tree.

```
BinaryNode *insert(BinaryNode *tree, Object datain)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        return Newnode(datain);
    }
    else
    {
        BinaryNode *temp = Newnode(datain);
        root = tree;
        while(tree != NULL)
        {
            if (datain.key < tree->item.key)
                tree = tree->left;
            else if (datain.key > tree->item.key)
                tree = tree->right;
            else
                  break; //Break to insert into the proper place
        }
        tree = temp;
        return root;
    }
}
```

Here is my source code for `printTree()` function, which I fairly assure that I did not get anything wrong here. However, I still provide it here to clarify my question.

```
oid printTree(BinaryNode *tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    printTree(root->left);
    printf("(%d - %s)-> ", tree->item.key, tree->item.name);
    printTree(root->right);
}
```

My problem: The output of my checking program is that it printed out only the first node of the tree. As I debug my source code, I find that except for the first insertion, it did not include the newly created node. However, I do have no idea how to fix it because I think my program is still logically algorithmetic.

Comment: In the `else` branch, you never create a new node. (This looks as if the code wants to be recursive, in which case you will get to the null case eventually.)

Comment: @MOehm I'm so sorry because I gave you all the older versions of my source code. I have edited it, Can you re-read it, please?

Comment: Well, `temp` and `tree` are only local variables, not visible from the outside. When you say `return root`, `temp` and `tree` go out of scpoe -- they will be invalid. You must store the pointer to the new node in the parent node's `left` or `right` members.

Comment: @MOehm I still do not catch your idea. You are right that ``temp`` and ``tree`` are local variables and I tend to do it like that because I want to do everything with ``tree`` with no fear of leaking or losing address's nodes of BST. Finally, I will return the ``root`` to return the head of the BST so it will be OK. As you can see from my source code, I have to change the address of a node to a proper position in ``while()`` loop. However, It can not insert in that place

Comment: Maybe you don't want to set root to tree? (first line inside of the while loop) Seems like that could cause something unexpected. root will no longer point to the head of tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except when you insert the first item, you don't store a link to the new node in the tree. Your local variables `temp` and `tree` go out of scope when you return. You must store a link to the new node in the existing structure of your tree, either as new root or as one of the `löeft` or `right` links of the new node's parent node.

One way to do that would be:

```
BinaryNode *insert(BinaryNode *root, Object datain)
{
    BinaryNode *prev = NULL;
    BinaryNode *curr = root;
    int whence = 0;

    while (curr) {
        if (datain.key == curr->item.key) return root;

        if (datain.key < curr->item.key) {
            curr = curr->left;
            whence = 0;
        } else {
            curr = curr->right;
            whence = 1;
        }
    }

    BinaryNode *temp = Newnode(datain);

    if (prev == NULL) {
        root = temp;
    } else if (whence == 0) {
        prev->left = temp;
    } else {
        prev->right = temp;
    }

    return root;
}
```

The Node pointer `prev` stores the parent of the current node. If it is null, the tree is initially empty and you must insert at the root. The flag `whence` tells you wheter you have arrived at the current node via the `left` or `right` branch, so that you know ahere to update.

(Also note how the allocation happens only afterwe have established that the node is to be inserted. Otherwise, returning early would leak the newly allocated node.)

This solution introduces two extra variables. You can reduce that by using a pointer to node pointer: At first, that pointer `p` points to the head pointer, when descending the tree, it points to where you come from, which is either the `left` or `right` member of the parent node:

```
BinaryNode *insert(BinaryNode *root, Object datain)
{
    BinaryNode **p = &root;

    while (*p) {
        if (datain.key == (*p)->item.key) return root;

        if (datain.key < (*p)->item.key) {
            p = &(*p)->left;
        } else {
            p = &(*p)->right;
        }
    }

    *p = NewNode(datain);

    return root;
}
```

You must still retun the node. This code is shorter, because it doesn't have to deal with the special case of inserting the first node and it doesn't have to distiguish between the leaf and right branches explicitly when inserting the new node.

If you are willing to change the function signature, there's one improvement to make: Pass a pointer to the head pointer instead of returning. That way, the head pointer in the calling function will be updated via `proot`:

```
void insert(BinaryNode **proot, Object datain)
{            
    while (*proot) {
        if (datain.key == (*proot)->item.key) return;

        if (datain.key < (*proot)->item.key) {
            proot = &(*proot)->left;
        } else {
            proot = &(*proot)->right;
        }
    }

    *proot = NewNode(datain);
}
```

You call this function like this:

```
BinaryNode *root = NULL;

insert(&root, mydata);
```

The redundancy of `root = insert(root, data)` is gone and you can't accidentially forget to upate the root pointer by omitting to store the return value.

Comment: I think that the final solution should be corrected because after you have changed the pointer of ``proot`` to the proper position and insert the new node, the head of the BST has been lost. How could your program maintain the head of the BST?

Comment: I don't know why but as I followed you source code (the second one), my compiler announced this message ``BinaryTree.h:112:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *p = NewNode(datain);``

Comment: About the warning: If so, your original code should give the same message. Surely, `NewNode` must return a `BinaryNode *`, no? Have you declared `NewNode` before you call it?

Comment: You misunderstand the last solution. If you understand the second solution -- namely that `p` midofies the root on the first insertion and the left/right links of the parent node otherwise --, you will see that the last solution is not really different, only that instead of modifying a local variable that holds the head node, it modifies the variable that holds the head node in the calling function _through the pointer_. After that, i.e. if there are already nodes, it just modifies the links l/r as before.

Comment: So your point is that I can just change content inside the pointer ``proot`` for no fear of losing the head of the BST? I feel it new to me because I think that if I use the pointer-to-pointer directly like this it will point to the last element so I will lose the head

Comment: But you still have the head: It's `root` in the function you call. Note how the last function doesn't return anything. On the first insertion, it updates that head, on subsequent insertions, it updates other links in the tree. The line `p = &(*p)->left/right` changes what is updated.  Also note that using `p` has the role of the `prev` pointer in the first code and that if the root is not null `*p` and `prev->left/right` are more or less equivalent: They add one level of indirection, so that you know where you came from. Only that `*p` is more general.

Comment: As I compile your last solution, my compiler gave a message: ``BinaryTree.h:102:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             root = &(*proot)->left;`` which is symmetric to ``root = &(*proot)->right``. I remind that ``root`` in my program is a global variable that holds the head of the BST. If ``root`` in your code plays a different role, please inform to me. Moreover, I do not conceive any function of ``root`` here, can you explain me more?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo on my part. I'm sorry about that. It must be `proot`, the pointer to root that you pass in when you `insert(&root, data)`.